# Why does the tab key sometimes not work when switching between fields in a user form?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, userform, vba

Here's how the user form looks.
[image: User form]

Most of the time when pressing the tab button, it goes to the next field, and of course, shift+tab makes it go to the previous field. **Well about 50% of the time when I open the file, the tab key doesn't do anything and inserts an actual tab space until I close it and reopen it again**; regardless, the fields all work. How do I fix this?

I do not have any code on it related to keys, except the escape key to close the window and that's it. Here's an image of the properties of the Store Number field. All of them have TabKeyBehavior to False, so it prevents tab spaces from being inserted.

[image]

Comment: Try putting in your `Userform_Initialize()` the line `TextBox1.SetFocus`. Then you've at least told the script what to have focus on.

Comment: It already has that actually.

Comment: Also running into this issue. I will let you know if I find a solution. This one is new for me. I wish MS would actually update VBA - one of the most underrated programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Coming to this party *very* late I know, but I at least have something to try.  I've found that a lot of people have had this issue, and nobody seems to know what the deal is.  It appears to be some "glitch" in VBA.

I went back to the user form and changed TabKeyBehavior for all the text boxes to True, saved the document, went back in and changed them all back to False and saved again.  This seems to clear up the problem, whatever it is.  It's a good idea to save a backup copy of the document in case it happens again.

Basically a variation of "turn it off then back on."  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I selected the first (set focus) textbox, changed the TabKeyBehavior to True then False and then the form worked as it is supposed to. I didn't have to save the spreadsheet between True and False or go the "off" "on" for the rest of the textboxes in the form.